# How do you start a new line in a string/mtext

Tags: vba, autocad

I am trying to get the text under Leadertext to display on separate lines. How do you show new line in VBA? so it comes out as

CB (Util)

E INV (Util)

```
  'Leader Text
    StartPoint(0) = points(6): StartPoint(1) = points(7): StartPoint(2) = points(8)
    LeaderTextWidth = 1
    LeaderText = ("CB " & Util & " E INV " & Util)
    Set LeaderAnnotation = ACAD.ActiveDocument.ModelSpace.AddMText(StartPoint, LeaderTextWidth, LeaderText)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ways. The `VBA.Constants` standard library module is your friend. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278800.aspx) describes them all.

---

**vbNewLine** represents a *new line* on the platform the code is running on:

```
LeaderText = ("CB " & Util & vbNewLine & " E INV " & Util)
```

That's usually your ideal solution. However sometimes your code could be sending strings to a system with Unix-style *new lines* from both Windows and Mac machines, so you need to be more careful or specific. That's why other constants exist.

**vbCrLf** makes a Windows new line with ASCII characters 10 and 13:

```
LeaderText = ("CB " & Util & vbCrLf & " E INV " & Util)
```

**vbLf** is ASCII 10, a *line feed*: `vbLf` is equivalent to `Chr(10)`.

**vbCr** is ASCII 13, a *carriage return*: `vbCr` is equivalent to `Chr(13)`.

Hence, this is also produces the exact same output (assuming Windows):

```
LeaderText = ("CB " & Util & vbCr & vbLf & " E INV " & Util)
```

Or

```
LeaderText = ("CB " & Util & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & " E INV " & Util)
```